# Getting Target host is not specified

Tags: java, http, prometheus, grafana

I am calling Prometheus server via Grafana. I am able to make below request using Postman but when I am trying the same URI with java code, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

My piece of code is as given below.

```java
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
String PM_UI_SERVER_URI = "http://" + PM_SERVER_HOST + ":" + getPMUiServerPort();
String uriStr= PM_UI_SERVER_URI + PM_SERVER_BASE_URI + queryString +"&start="+String.valueOf(startTime)+"&end="+String.valueOf(endTime)+"&step=150";
//logger.info("Execute Query uri string: "+uriStr);
String str="http://10.61.244.58:31000/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query_range?query=em_core_used_heap_mem_mb{job=\"eric-em-om-server\"}&start=1592981880&end=1592982180&step=15";
String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(str,"UTF-8");
//URI uri = new URI(encodedurl);
//HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.61.244.58:31000/api/datasources/1");
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(encodedurl);
httpget.addHeader("Authorization", token);
httpget.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
```

Can someone please help as I am stuck here.

Comment: Whats the output of `logger.info("Execute Query uri string: "+uriStr);` (commented out line). Assuming its correct, are you able to `ping` the `host` from the box this code is running from?

Comment: Yes @RobEvans, I am able to ping.

Comment: If you can ping the host then the problem is with the url, rather than a problem communicating with the host. Test whether `telnet 10.61.244.58 31000` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build up the URL piece by piece rather than going straight for the completed URL. You can do this in a debug session using the expression builder in intelliJ IDE.

1. set breakpoint at the line `... = httpClient.execute(httpget);` and exercise this code from a test/running the application in debug mode.
2. highlight `httpClient.execute(httpget)`
3. either right click this selection and click "Expression builder" OR use `Alt`+`F8`
4. now try to perform the execute the GET (`HttpGet`) request for `http://10.61.244.58:31000/`
5. ensure you're getting a 200 response status or equivalent.
6. next you should be able to add the next bit like `http://10.61.244.58:31000/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query_range` (Note I'd also try without the `proxy` as the URL may be problematic because your requests are being proxied according to the docs here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/data_source/#data-source-proxy-calls

I'd try then adding the query params individually and combined. This isn't going to necessarily resolve your problem... but if you can at the same time tail any logs on the grafana server/proxy server you may get some more detailed information that will help lead your investigation.